# ATmegaXXX V, P, does it matter for compilation?

Tags: gcc, avr, atmega

I used a ATmega649 before but then switched to ATmega649V.

Does it matter which MCU version given to the compiler, ATmega649, ATmega649V or ATmega649P?

I understand it as the architecture is exactly the same it is only some powersaving that is somehow achieved without changing the architecture that is the difference?

Using avr-gcc.

Answer (score 1):

well, you can use an "almost" compatible architecture with no harm, though you have to triple check the datasheet that there's no difference in the way registers are setup otherwise your program won't work, or worst will work until a feature is failing. It is usually a source of frustration when you've forgotten you've been using a close enough, but not exactly the architecture you're targetting.

I don't know well enough the Atmega649X, and I won't thoroughly read the lengthy datasheets to find those differences. So if you decide to do it, be careful, and don't forget about that!

Answer (score 1):

usually the additional letters signalize differences in max speed, supply voltage ratings or power consumptions. the core itself is compatible. so if numbers match, it is no difference from the compilers point of view.

however the flash tool may recognize them as different parts and require correct settings.